# Why does jQuery(this).css('background-image') return the browser URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, foreach

I have three divs as shown below.

```
<div id="div#product_img_wrapper">
    <div id="product_design1" class="timage"  style="z-index: 20; background-image: url('');"></div>
    <div id="product_design2" class="timage"  style="z-index: 20; background-image: url('');"></div>
    <div id="product_design3" class="timage"  style="z-index: 20; background-image: url('');"></div>
</div>
```

I use below jquery function to loop trough above divs as below.

```
jQuery('div#product_img_wrapper div').each(function(){

            var background = jQuery(this).css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace(')','');

            if(background != 'none')
            {
                console.log(jQuery(this));
                console.log(background);
            } 


        });
```

Output

```
"http://localhost/project/index.php?option=com_project&controller=project&task=project&method=1"
"http://localhost/project/index.php?option=com_project&controller=project&task=project&method=1"
"http://localhost/project/index.php?option=com_project&controller=project&task=project&method=1"
```

What I'm trying to do is get the background-image attribute of the each div. But it returns me this URL which browser shows ? What's wrong with the above code? Why does jQuery(this).css('background-image') return the browser URL ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a background-image URL? It looks blank in your code

Comment: Why would you have `div#` inside of your id attribute? This will for sure confuse the jQuery selector engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url('')` is a relative URL that resolves to "here".

You are getting the URL you specified, just resolved to absolute form instead of the raw relative form that you entered.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is relative and it's set to absolute.

You should write this to get the background :

```
var background = jQuery(this).css('background-image').replace('url(' + location.href,'').replace(')','');
```

Comment: My bad, I wrote `this.href` instead of `location.href`.

Comment: still the same. But thanks anyway. I figured it out